# How to get the PHP Version?

Tags: php

Is there a way to check the version of PHP that executed a particular script from within that script? So for example, the following snippet

```
$version = way_to_get_version();
print $version;
```

would print 5.3.0 on one machine, and 5.3.1 on another machine.

Comment: BTW if you google for `php version`, the link to the documentation of `phpversion()` is the first result...

Comment: Note: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php#84424

Comment: @FelixKling sad times when this SO question is higher in Google than the actual documentation.

Answer (score 115):

```
$version = phpversion();
print $version;
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php)

However, for best practice, I would use the constant `PHP_VERSION`. No function overhead, and cleaner IMO.

Also, be sure to use `version_compare()` if you are comparing PHP versions for compatibility.

Comment: It's just called `version_compare()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I get for recalling from memory!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php#84424 i would always use `PHP_VERSION` for best practice

Comment: here PHP_VERSION[0] == 5 or PHP_VERSION[0] == 7, can compare version 5 or 7 version respective way...

Comment: @user1635700 So long as there isn't a 10th major release :P

Comment: @alex its depnds hows important to particule. Utilize that's way.

Comment: "no function overhead". Really, there's absolutely no need to worry about that in cases like this. You could easily call the function a thousand times and the performance hit would still be non-existent.

Answer (score 34):

Technically the best way to do it is with the constant PHP_VERSION as it requires no function call and the overhead that comes with it.

php 5

```bash
echo $PHP_VERSION;
```

That does not work in 7+ however, you can use:

php7.x

```bash
echo PHP_VERSION;
```

Not sure about php8.x though.
constants are always faster then function calls.

Comment: Variables?! That's a constant!

Comment: In this context, yes, since I'm referring to a definite programming website in the scope of this conversation, hence the definite article :)

Answer (score 20):

You can either use the `phpversion()` function or the `PHP_VERSION` constant.

To compare versions you should always rely on [`version_compare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php).

Comment: "*To compare versions you should always rely on version_compare().*" Care to add why? (am enquiring, not insinuating you are incorrect)

Comment: @James: `version_compare()` is simply more powerful than arithmetic operators: http://ideone.com/0QQwq7. The PHP manual has some good examples.

Answer (score 13):

.........

```
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5', '>='))
{
       // act accordintly
}
```

Comment: This is what i need

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [phpversion()](http://php.net/phpversion).

```
echo "Current version is PHP " . phpversion();
```

Answer (score 4):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php

Returns exactly the "5.3.0".

Answer (score 4):

[`phpversion()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) will tell you the currently running PHP version.

Answer (score 3):

you can use phpversion() function to get php version

eg. `echo 'PHP version: ' . phpversion();`

Answer (score 2):

You can use phpversion(); function to find the current version

```
    <?php echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`phpversion()` is one way.   As John conde said, `PHP_VERSION` is another (that I didn't know about 'till now).

You may also be interested in [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need any of the following

- `phpversion()`
- `PHP_VERSION`
- `version_compare()`

To properly compare the current version.

You can use the `PHP_VERSION_ID` constant. This is for 7.2 and its NOT 720 think 70.20.0

```
if ( PHP_VERSION_ID < 70200 ) {
   echo "php version is lower than 7.2";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you typecast the output of phpversion() to a floating point number, it will give you the major and minor version parts. This way you can implement PHP compatibility easily.

```
$version = (float)phpversion();
if ($version > 7.0) {
    //do something for php7.1 and above.
} elseif ($version === 7.0) {
    //do something for php7.0
} else {
    //do something for php5.6 or lower.
}
```

Comment: You should really use `version_compare()`, as this is what it is designed for.

Answer (score -1):

Surprised this answer hasn't been added (here's how you would actually run this from a command line):

```
php -r "echo 'PHP version: ' . phpversion();"
```