# Function in PHP deprecated, what should I use now?

Tags: php, deprecated

I have this code in one of my classes

```
 public function __call($method, $args) {

        array_unshift($args, $method);

        call_user_method_array('view', $this, $args);

    }
```

We've since switched servers, and they must use a newer version of PHP5, and I get the following message

> ```
> Function call_user_method_array() is deprecated
> ```

Is there where I should use *reflection*? What exactly is it, and how would I use it to modify my code above to work as it used to?

Comment: Stack overflow users might be able to tell me things the manual does not. E.g. Best practices, tips etc

Comment: "Function in PHP deprecated, what should I use now?" The answer you accepted and called "perfect" merely links to and quotes the manual.

Comment: Well, in this case there wasn't anything extra to add, but it still solved my problem. Who ever said Stack Overflow shouldn't be a first place to find things out anyway? There are plenty of manual type questions on here.

Comment: "There are plenty of manual type questions on here." I have to concede you that.

Comment: There are plenty of manual type questions which have received more thorough answers. Take the "How do I get the PHP version" question. The answer `phpversion()` was brought up, but users added the benefits of using the constant, and the need to use `version_compare()` when trying to determine if a PHP package was suitable for an application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113955

Answer (score 24, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-method-array.php

> The call_user_method_array() function is deprecated as of PHP 4.1.0.

**New way:**

```
<?php
// Old:
// call_user_method_array('view', $this, $args);
// New:
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'view'), $args);
?>
```