# can't enable mssql extension in php.ini?

Tags: sql-server, xampp

I'm using xampp 1.7.1 (i know it's an old version) and i need to enable the `extension=php_mssql.dll` - with the extension enabled my appache won't start? If i disable the extension it let's me start appache. I was having problems with my site using `mssql_connect()` and I was told that enabling the extension in my php.ini would help? I'm using mssql server 2008 express r2. I'm not entirely sure what php version xampp 1.7.1 is but could this be a factor? Someone mentioned I needed php 5.2

Why won't appache let me enable the extension?

Comment: See [How to get the PHP Version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113955/how-to-get-the-php-version) or simply run `php -v`. PHP/5.2 is terribly outdated. I hope you aren't using something even older.

Comment: As about the "Why Apache" question, there's a way to know: have a look at the Apache log folder. Most likely, PHP is telling it that `php_mssql.dll` cannot load for a given reason and Apache decides to abort.

Answer (score 0):

Follow what is posted here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php.

If still you cannot make it work try using the new SQLSRV driver for PHP. It can be downloaded at the [Microsoft Downloads](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239647) website.