# How to know the version of PHP is used on xampp?

Tags: xampp, htdocs

How to know what version of PHP is used on my xampp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the PHP Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113955/how-to-get-the-php-version)

Comment: Brother, my answer is different though question is same.

Comment: it's a good question... not sure why strange comments and downvotes.

Answer (score 32):

If you are using new version of xampp.

Try http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 14):

1. Put this code in your root directory or htdocs folder of xampp:
2. `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
3. Save it as phpinfo.php and point your browser to it (this could be http://localhost/phpinfo.php)
4. [Example: random image (Click Here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCEBU.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

First open your Locate directory where using Xampp

```
C:/Xampp/php
```

Type `cmd` on folder address bar and hit `Enter`

And then Type command `php -v`

Answer (score 1):

Go to xampp control panel start the apache and mysql and click the admin besides the MySQL. After phpmyadmin page open, there you can see php version, Apache version and MySQL version in that open page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, I navigated to C:\xampp\php, then I right clicked on php.exe -> properties -> "details" tab -> file version