# PHP version Check

Tags: php

So I'm basically trying to create a tool that used across platforms, including sometimes legacy php version.

I don't plan on supporting anything less than 5.4 so I'd like to use something like below; however, instead of the application dying, I get various syntax errors. One of the first to start alerting is using brackets to define arrays.

Is there anyway to get around this?

```
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4', '<')) {
    die('This tool does not support anything < PHP 5.4<br>Your PHP version is: '.phpversion() );
}

$array= ['a','b','c'];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the PHP Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113955/how-to-get-the-php-version)

Comment: PHP checks the script syntax before running any of it. So if you use new syntax, it will never get to the `version_compare()`. You have to stick to old syntax.

Comment: @Seblor He already knows how to get the version, don't you see the code?

Comment: @Barmar I may have skipped it, I read the question before the edit. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The file you are doing a version_check for should simply not use any newer PHP features or include any files that do. If you want the version_check to work on PHP 4, it can only use PHP 4 features.

Comment: It can call newer functions, it just has to limit itself to legacy syntax. The version check will work as long as the syntax is valid.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, this was is what I was afraid of.   The brackets would by far be the easiest thing to address.