# How to make a checking upto third level of a string like version checking like '8.1.1' is greater that '8.1.0'?

Tags: php, version

I have a raw php (vanilla php) script and upgraded php v8.1.0. And now I don't want to run the script in a lower version of that. I want to make that check-in raw PHP as I don't have a composer or don't use any framework, how can I do that?

Actually I want to make a checking of my own third level number like

if ('7.4.9' > '8.1.0') not using php built in function
in some case we also see version: '^7.4'. In that case what also can be done.

Can anyone give any suggestions please, or anywhere I can get the answers?

Comment: What do you mean by "raw php"? Do you mean the _code_? Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113955/how-to-get-the-php-version and probably [version_compare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the PHP Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113955/how-to-get-the-php-version)

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, here raw php i mean vanilla php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean *vanilla PHP* instead of *raw PHP*.
You can test the PHP version into the script like this:

```
if (phpversion() < '8.1.0') {
   die ('At least PHP version 8.1.0 is required');
}
```

If you need a more granular comparison on the subversion or on the release version you can use [version_compare()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) which does all dirty job for you:

```php
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '8.1.0', '<')) {
   die ('At least PHP version 8.1.0 is required');
}
```

Constants are also available *'for all tastes'*:

- PHP_VERSION
- PHP_VERSION_ID
- PHP_MAJOR_VERSION
- PHP_MINOR_VERSION
- PHP_RELEASE_VERSION

Comment: if (phpversion() < '8.1.0') {
   die ('At least PHP version 8.1.0 is required');
}

Does php check up to the third level '8.1.1' ? third level means 3 of '8.1.1'. If so does it type cast to string float?

if ('8.1.1'  > '8.1.0') 
Can you please explain this, how checking happening here?
say like  converting to if (811 > 810 )

Comment: @Imtiaze i've added some information to my answer about your additional explanation request